# Rails 5: How to implement a conditional validation for an ActiveModel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

As the code below shows, I am trying to validate an form value of an ActiveModel object based on the value of a checkbox of the same form.
If the box is checked (I made sure it will return `true` not `1`) the validation on `order_number` should be deactivated, as the field is being deactivated as well (by JS). The naive approach shown below, using the attribute that is connected to the checkbox `not_a_customer` as conditional for the validation of `order_number` didn't work.

What else can I try?

I have an ActiveModel class:

```
class SupportCase
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include ActiveModel::Validations

  attr_accessor(:email, :os, :inquiry_type, :order_number, :first_name, :last_name, :message, :not_a_customer)

  validates :order_number, presence: true,
                           numericality: { only_integer: true },
                           length: { in: (4..5), message: 'doh' },
                           unless: :not_a_customer
end
```

And a form for creating support cases:

```
= simple_form_for @support_case, html: { class: 'form inset' } do |f|
  .row
    .col.sm-6
      .row{ id: 'order-row' }
        .col.sm-6
          = f.input :order_number, input_html: { class: 'icon-field hash-icon' }
        .col.sm-6
          .label-title{ title: t("simple_form.labels.support_case.hint") }
            = f.input :not_a_customer, as: :boolean do
              = f.check_box :not_a_customer, {}, "true", "false"

    .col.sm-6
      = f.input :email, input_html: { type: 'email', required: 'true' }
      = f.input :first_name, input_html: { type: 'text' }
      = f.input :last_name, input_html: { type: 'text' }

    .col.sm-12
      ~ f.input :message, as: 'text', input_html: { required: 'true' }

    %button.btn.btn-action
      = t('views.contact.form.submit')
```

Comment: What error are you getting when you try the above code?

Comment: No errors, it is just not validating as I want it. I can leave the order_number blank and the box unchecked. Only with a checked box it should be possible to leave the order number blank

Comment: If I understand it right, only if the checkbox is not checked, the validations should run. Right?

Comment: exactly, the checkbox is saying 'I am not a customer`. no customer no order_number, no validations for order_number.

Comment: check the value of `not_a_customer`. I suspect you are just getting a string instead of a boolean value, which is always truthy.

Comment: that is correct, thanks!

Comment: @Flip, I guess you can answer your own question now :)

Comment: I'll wait a bit, maybe Edmund wants to get the credits, and he'd deserve them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value of `not_a_customer`. You are just getting a string instead of a boolean value, which is always truthy ("true", "false" are both truthy value).

In Rails, you can do `not_a_customer.to_bool` to convert it into boolean.

The `checkbox` does not convert your value into `boolean`, because `params` is parsed as if they are all strings (including `int`, `string`, `boolean` values).

Comment: You are absolutely right about the string values. Interestingly, after changing this line (which I added to make the checkbox say true/false instead of 1/0): `= f.check_box :not_a_customer, {}, 'true', 'false'`to `= f.check_box :not_a_customer, {}, true, false` it suddenly works, even though in the params hash it still turns up as a string value.

Comment: @Flip hmm.. that's interesting. But I wouldn't rely on that too much and would still use `to_bool` just in case. I need to look into the param parser. keep in mind, when the request is sent from the client to server, it's just one giant string. so maybe rails 5 would check if the string comes with the quote or not and determine what to parse it to...

Comment: @Flip a good example I've encountered was, empty input converts into empty string (maybe an obvious one), but if given the same logic, it should be `nil`. so my takeaway was not relying on the magic.

Comment: @Edmung Lee: you're right, I will follow your advise. Thanks again.